# How to extract only version number from a string

Tags: powershell

I am extracting oracle version from windows using powershell command and i get result as `10.2.0.3.0Patch2`, however i need to extract only numeric  value i.e. `10.2.0.3.0` (only version number). Any way we can do it ?

Version info extracted is =

```
10.2.0.3.0 Production, 10.2.0.3.0Patch2 Production, 10.2.0.5.0 Production, 11.2.0.4.0 Production
```

Comment: Please edit the question and show how the version info is extracted.

Comment: RegeX, `Split()`, using `indexOf()` for character adressing. Choose one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a regular expression to extract a substring. Example:

```
"10.2.0.3.0Patch2" | Select-String '((?:\d{1,3}\.){4}\d{1,3})' | ForEach-Object {
   $_.Matches[0].Groups[1].Value
}
# Outputs the string '10.2.0.3.0'
```

You can read more about regular expressions by reading the `about_Regular_Expressions` help topic:

```
PS C:\> help about_Regular_Expressions
```